# Office365 PnP Taxonomy Picker: How can i get selected/picked value from Taxonomy Picker

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, jsom, office-365-developer

How can i get picked/selected value from Taxonomy Picker "input".
I have have implemented my Taxonomy field like showed in this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2014/03/13/taxonomy-picker-in-sharepoint-provider-hosted-app/)

And its working fine, the only thing i cant figure out is how to get the selected / picked taxonomy value from the input field. I need that value to further use it in my REST query to save in a list.

Iam working on a SharePoint Add-in app-part, using AngularJS, bootstrap, JSOM.
Any help will be appriciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get it using something like this:

```
function getTaxonomyControlObjectValue() {
     var taxCtlObj = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ControlObject($("#" + scope.contentControlId).get(0));
     var termValue = taxCtlObj.getRawText();
     return termValue;
}
```

*You mentioned you were using AngularJS so that is why the scope object is up there. For anyone else, just replace the `scope.contentControlId` with your actual ID.*

Answer (score 0):

Oki, i can get or se the value:

```
var taxPickerIndex = $("#taxPickerOpenSingle").get(0);
```

> [{"Id":"e0a1f57a-6746-4ecc-b119-47f2ff80a1ea","Name":"L3-2 Forbedringsprosess","PathOfTerm":"L3 Lede og forbedre;L3-2 Forbedringsprosess","Children":[],"Level":1,"RawTerm":null}]

but when it comes to line with code:

```
var taxCtlObj = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ControlObject($("#" + scope.contentControlId).get(0));
```

I get an error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ControlObject' of undefined
>
> Blockquote

iam running my code in a SharePoint online, ClientWebPart/App-Part as they call it now. Using AngularJS/Bootstrap jQuery, JSOM, and JAvascript....

Comment: i was not ref to script correct way: need to call                         SP.SOD.executeFunc('ScriptForWebTaggingUI.js', false, test);
and put this line in default.aspx :     <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="scriptforwebtaggingui.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />